# How to Implement Inheritance pattern in Go

Tags: go, inheritance

I am experimenting to migrate a nodejs system (TypeScript) to golang. It's going well except I am having trouble in reproducing the following in idiomatic go

I have the following abstract class:

```
abstract class BaseSensor {
  beforeStart() {/*default implementation*/ }
  afterStart() {/*default implementation*/ }
  shutdown() {/*default implementation*/ }
  abstract process();

  work() {
    this.beforeStart()
    //...
    this.afterStart()
    //...
    this.process()
    //...
    this.shutdown()
  }
}
```

then I have some concrete classes/sensors which implement at least the `process()` method and optionally any of the other lifecycle methods.

```
class SensorA extends BaseSensor {
  process() {
    //SensorA specific processing
  }
}

class SensorB extends BaseSensor {
  beforeStart() {
    //SensorB overriding beforeStart()
  }
  process() {
    //SensorB specific processing
  }
}
```

`SensorA` only implements the `process()` method and doesn't override anything else. `SensorB` implements `process()` and also overrides `beforeStart()`.

What is the correct way of doing something like this in golang?

Edit: My situation is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261032/how-to-implement-an-abstract-class-in-go) because i also want to optionally override other methods

Comment: This is a not TypeScript related

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement an abstract class in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261032/how-to-implement-an-abstract-class-in-go)

Comment: You should get more familiar with Go before attempting to translate TypeScript code to Go. For one thing, Go has no concept of inheritance; in Go, subtyping is achieved solely through (implicitly satisfied) interfaces. You should get familiar with that first.

Comment: Go does not support inheritance,however it does support composition. (example: https://golangbot.com/inheritance/)

Comment: can you guys please break the flow and mention an approach i should flow to achieve same objectives. i know go has no inheritance